# how to make deployable war file for spring boot 1.2.3 in tomcat 7

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

What are the configurations required to build a spring boot application as deploy able war, which can be deployed in tomcat 7 running on java 8.

After hours of debugging i am able to get the war file but once deployed to tomcat it is not being deployed correctly and apis are not accessible and give a 404 error.

The catalina log file is as follows:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/test.war
May 13, 2015 1:10:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
```

Pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
    <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
  <!--  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>-->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Application.class file

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jni.Global;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    private static Application application=new Application();
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {

        return application
                .showBanner(true)
                .parent(Global.class)
                .sources(this.application)
                .profiles("container")
                ;
    }


    @Bean
    public Filter characterEncodingFilter() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return characterEncodingFilter;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Comment: yes i did, tried the mentioned steps but still landed up with same logs.
didnt get an error but the rest calls are not accessible.

Comment: `.sources(this.application)` looks suspect to me. It should be `.sources(Application.class)`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the static field `application` and change the return value of the configure method as following:

```
return application
            .showBanner(true)
            .parent(Global.class)
            .sources(Application.class)
            .profiles("container")
            ;
```

Answer (score 0):

@SpringBootApplication
public class ApiApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(ApiApplication.class);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To create a deployable Tomcat 7 war file read this [guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html):

1. `<packaging>war</packaging>`
2. override: `SpringBootServletInitializer.configure`

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
       @Override
       protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
           return application.sources(Application.class);
       }
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
       }
   }
   ```
3. change `pom.xml`

   ```
   <properties>
       <tomcat.version>7.0.78</tomcat.version>
       <servlet-api.version>3.0.1</servlet-api.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
           <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>  <!-- provided: tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar -->
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
           <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
           <scope>runtime</scope> <!-- runtime: tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -->
       </dependency>
       <!-- remove it:
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
       -->
   </dependencies>
   ```